# How to save a document uploaded in yammer in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I wonder if I can do this in Yammer:

- Upload a document in Yammer.
- Save the document in a SharePoint document library instead of Yammer.

Is it possible?

Comment: check developer API of Yammer, if is there any way to download uploaded files you cant do it

Comment: following event:
Upload a file to Yammer and save it to a SharePoint library .
I can not find information about events in Yammer .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hook into a file upload event, or receive a callback/webhook from Yammer today. What you can do is monitor the files.csv from the [Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api) and take action based on the addition of new files. This isn't the most pleasing solution, but may be workable for your needs.